# IOS - in drawRect func layer properties can not be changed?

Tags: ios, swift, layer, drawrect

I created a class that inherit from view object (UIButton)
I don't understand why when i'm trying to change the backgroundColor that i add in drawRect func by init or by awakeFromNib func it succeed,
**but** when i'm trying to change property of layer that i add 
in drawRect func (like self.layer.cornerRadius), it doesn't change by init or by awakeFromNib func.

Two Questions:
1. can someone explain to me what's happened behind the scenes?
2. how can i change property of layer that was added in drawRect func?

Sorry for my shaky English
I hope it is clear enough :)

Here is my simple sample code:

```
import UIKit

class Btn:UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.backgroundColor=UIColor.cyanColor();
        self.layer.borderWidth=1;
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.backgroundColor=UIColor.brownColor(); // it was changed to brown
        self.layer.borderWidth=3; // it changed to 3
        self.layer.cornerRadius=20;// it doesn't changed to 20 
        // it's stay 5 from drawRect func (down here) whyyy???            
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor();
        self.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  `drawRect` gets called after `awakeFromNib`, so if you set it in both then the `drawRect` is just going to overwrite the one in `awakeFromNib`

Comment: so why the backgroundColor that i get is brown, according to your answer the drawRect overwrite the one in awakeFromNib so why i dont see greenColor??

Answer (score 1):

> how can i change property of layer that was added in drawRect func?

Don't. Don't change any properties of any layers in `drawRect`, and don't added any layers in `drawRect`. The only thing you should be doing in `drawRect` is *drawing* the view's content. This code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor();
    self.layer.cornerRadius=5;
}
```

...is just wrong. Delete it.

Comment: Thanks for responding and O.K i will not... but you don't really answer my question or given a good explanation.  if i shouldn't have doing it than why when i remove the awakeFromNiv func from the code i can see that  layer properties of the button  in drawRect func are set and working and there isn't any error after running the code??

Comment: I didn't say remove the `awakeFromNib`. `awakeFromNib` is a great place to configure your view with layers and background color. `drawRect` is not.